# Issue with ggplot, coming out as straight line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to find the relationship between eating ice cream and playing games.

My code:

```
sizedata = read.table(file.choose(), header= T, sep =',')
View(sizedata)
summary(sizedata)
lm(Icecream ~ Games, sizedata)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sizedata, aes(x=Icecream, y=Games)) + geom_point() + ylim(0,1000) + 
  stat_smooth(method='lm')

ggplot(sizedata, aes(x=Icecream, y=Games)) + geom_point() + ylim(0,1000) + 
  geom_smooth()
```

The graph comes out looking like:

[image]

[This is my CSV file with the data](https://sakai.rutgers.edu/access/content/attachment/f1bcea4c-5492-40d2-b6c0-3eed1dee4aaa/Assignments/f0b3877f-db2c-466a-8d8d-41b61a6f0045/dating.csv)

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput(head(sizedata,10))` and add the output to the **question.**

Comment: Your ylim is too high to make sense of the fit

Comment: Why did you set the y-axis to show values up to 1000? It doesn't seem like that represents your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Russ Hyde and @camille pointed out - your `ylim` parameter is too high. Try to change it to lower - like `ylim(0,100)` or `ylim(0,50)`.

Comment: @katelynn767 : Cool, so is the issue solved, and did I answer your question?